# kill document event with jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I search a lot but don't find what I want...
I create a plugin (table built dynamically).
I need to catch some event, but like my table is not here on load event, I use

```
 $(document).on("click", '.Delete', function () {...});
```

When I use my plugin in ModalPopup, I need to destroy table, cause I need to recreate table after.

```
$r.children().remove();
```

Until here all is good.

But When I recreate table and click on delete button I see my event play 2 times... I forget to kill event link to my table. I see lot of exemple with $(selector).off or .unbind... but never on document.

Someone can help me?

Comment: have you tried `$(document).off("click", '.Delete')` ??

Comment: @Yannicklngenierie It should be like $(document).off().on("click", '.Delete', function () {...});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code that will be used as a plugin, or simply when working with a large code base, best practice is to attach and remove events using namespaces so that the code will not inadvertently remove event handlers attached by other code. Use `.off()`;

```
 $( "body" ).off( "click", ".Delete" );
```

Comment: Sorry, I see off event can kill, I see document.ON, but don't try document.OFF ...